# setTimeOut without delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

The goal is for the pictures to transition into each other.

I started it off with the first picture having 1 opacity and the other three having a 0 opacity.

**How could I go about making it start transitioning from the start and then continuing the transition loop every 12 seconds. I don't want to wait 12 seconds to start the transition**

Here is my HTML with inline CSS

```
    <img id="01BrunetteGirl" style="width:100%; opacity:1;" src="images/brunettesmiling.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="02ManAndWife" style="width:100%; opacity:0;" src="images/manandwife.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="03GlassesMan" style="width:100%; opacity:0;" src="images/manwithglasses.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="04BlondeGirl" style="width:100%; opacity:0;" src="images/blondegirlsmile.jpg" alt="" />
```

And here is my Javascript

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("01BrunetteGirl").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("02ManAndWife").style.opacity = "1";
                    document.getElementById("03GlassesMan").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("04BlondeGirl").style.opacity = "0";
                }, 3000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("01BrunetteGirl").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("02ManAndWife").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("03GlassesMan").style.opacity = "1";
                    document.getElementById("04BlondeGirl").style.opacity = "0";
                }, 6000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("01BrunetteGirl").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("02ManAndWife").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("03GlassesMan").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("04BlondeGirl").style.opacity = "1";
                }, 9000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("01BrunetteGirl").style.opacity = "1";
                    document.getElementById("02ManAndWife").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("03GlassesMan").style.opacity = "0";
                    document.getElementById("04BlondeGirl").style.opacity = "0";
                }, 12000);
            }, 12000);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your code works as is: https://jsfiddle.net/wc0sugut/ (I changed the image references and style)

Comment: @joemfb you're right it works.  That was weird. It started working. But another issue is that it takes 12 seconds to start because of SetInterval. How would I go about making it work right from the beginning as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code like below

```
 var currentImageIndex = 0;
 setInterval(function() {
    var imageArrayIds = ["01BrunetteGirl", "02ManAndWife", "03GlassesMan", "04BlondeGirl"];
    if(currentImageIndex > 3) {
        currentImageIndex = 0;
    }

    for(var index in imageArrayIds) {
        document.getElementById(imageArrayIds[index]).style.opacity = (currentImageIndex == index ? "1" : "0");
    }

    currentImageIndex++;
 }, 3000);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wc0sugut/1/)**

**[Working Demo with jQuery animate effect](https://jsfiddle.net/wc0sugut/2/)**

Comment: Oh wow. That's amazing. I just had to change the originally opacity for the forth and first picture so that it didn't look like it was stuck on the first picture for 6 seconds. How would I go about making it fade instead of a abrupt transition?

Comment: For fade in out thing user jQuery as it has inbuilt methods to do so.

Comment: Does fade in and fade out use opacity to do so?

Comment: no it just hide that but if you want to only play around with opacity there is a method "animate" in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Late, and there's a good accepted answer, but you could build on Kundan's approach and automatically iterate through the images without first defining them in an array. Furthermore, by simply changing the image's `classname` instead we can move *all* the presentational properties such as opacity and the animation to the stylesheet thus allowing you to pick and choose the display and animation styles independently of the JavaScript.

[View the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL3dwhto/) or check out the snippet below.
Or check out [this jsFiddle with different style and animation](http://jsfiddle.net/zL3dwhto/1) (but no change to JS)

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll("#images img"),
    i=images.length-1;

(function next(){   
    i++;    
    images[i-1].className="";
    if(i>=images.length){i=0;}
    images[i].className="active";
    setTimeout(function(){next();},3000);
})();
```

```css
#images img{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 1.0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) scale(0.2);
    transform:rotate(180deg) scale(0.2);
}
#images img.active {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200&text=brunettesmiling.jpg" alt="brunette smiling" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200&text=manandwife.jpg" alt="man and wife" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200&text=manwithglasses.jpg" alt="man with glasses" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200&text=blondegirlsmile.jpg" alt="blonde girl smile" />
</div>
```

FYI. You can do this [entirely in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/zL3dwhto/3/). I wouldn't recommend it but its there as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a very small initial delay-time (e.g. 100) and set it to your desired delay-time within the function:

```js
var delay = 100;

function foo() {
  document.getElementById("01BrunetteGirl").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("02ManAndWife").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("03GlassesMan").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("04BlondeGirl").style.opacity = "0";
  delay = 12000;
  setTimeout(foo, delay);
}
```